# how to show last quarter data in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have a dashboard where I have data for each month for last 1 year.

Now I need to show data for last quarter (July-Sep)

Could anyone please help me what is the formula we need to write to get last quarter.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT (based on question update):

```
sum(
    if (    QUARTER([Date]) = QUARTER(DATEADD('quarter',-1,TODAY()))
        and YEAR([Date]) = YEAR(DATEADD('quarter',-1,TODAY()))
       ) then [Value]
    end
)
```

If you're using Tableau version older than 2019.3, you have to replace QUARTER with:

```
datepart('Quarter', [Date])
```

Comment: Hi Fabio or I just need sum of last months data as attached in main question which gives my last quarter data.Could you help please

Comment: still not sure about your error... anyway, please look at answer edit based on your sample to get only last quart value

Comment: Its not taking quarter for date field.Throwing that unknown function quarter called

Comment: I'm copying-pasting my calculated field and it's working... QUARTER is one of the date function provieded and documented: https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-gb/functions_functions_date.htm

Comment: did you try to create another calculated filed using QUARTER just to see if it comes up in the suggested functions' list? can you find quarter in that list?

Comment: Probably you're not using the latest Tableau version (2020.3)... check the add-on in the answer... Remember to specify which version you're using if it's not the latest